# counting the number of posts

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to find the number of input boxes that aren't empty, but I'm getting a value of 1 every time. what am I doing wrong?

```
foreach( $_POST as $key=> $value ) {
    if ($value!='' && $key!='add') {
        $count =  count($value);
    }  
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: You're not summing anything up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're simply redefining the `$count` variable to be `count($value)` (which is always `1` since `$value` is not an array), not incrementing it.

Use the increment operator instead to add 1 to `$count` when appropriate:

```
$count ++;
```

You're also probably better using `empty(..)` for your checks, like so:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    if($key != 'add' && !empty($value))
    {
        $count++;
    }
}
echo $count;
```